# Using ether-wake reports error "sendto: Network is down"

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

The command `sudo ether-wake xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` prints

```
sendto: Network is down
```

for all MAC addresses I plug in. I couldn't find any information on how to fix this - I'm clearly connected to WLAN on the PC I run the command on (sendto and ether-wake *are* able to send the magic package over wireless, as long as the receiver has a LAN-cable connection, right?).

Here's what `ifconfig` shows me:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 1003  bytes 88142 (86.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1003  bytes 88142 (86.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:99:2c:9a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::aed1:b8ff:febf:9eb9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether ac:d1:b8:bf:9e:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 35078  bytes 30784921 (29.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 3645
    TX packets 29962  bytes 5021667 (4.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 19
```

I think `wlp2s0` is what I've seen being referred to as `eth0`, as shown by:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
[    5.199702] eth0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[    5.306314] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from eth0
```

No idea how that renaming even happened or how I can change that, by the way. Any chance this might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a known issue, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1149502, and there is a fix, https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2015-15922.